# How are you supposed to use from in RUN --mount=type=cache,from=foo

Tags: dockerfile, docker-buildkit

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypecache
[image: RUN --mount=type-cache options]

Is `from` supposed to be used with multi stage builds?
What is an example use case?

Examples would be useful.
All examples I've seen are for a single target